# How do I loop through textboxes and clear them out?

Tags: c#

How do I remove all data in all my textboxes in C# using a loop. The list of the textboxes is called listoftextboxes. Also, how would I do the same thing with labels?

Can I use a removeall or clear or ...?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example; create a version of your code that you can share in your answer, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66500558/edit). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format your posted code.

Comment: Show your code.  Also, WinForms? WPF?  ASP.Net?

Comment: There is no code to show I have 10 textboxes. I am trying to clear with a clear button that loops through them. All of the textboxes are in a list called listoftextboxes

Comment: You have `listoftextboxes` so that's something.  How is that populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use `List<T>.ForEach` and `TextBox.Clear`:

```
listoftextboxes.ForEach(txt => txt.Clear());
```

with a label(or TextBox) you can use:

```
listoflabels.ForEach(lbl => lbl.Text = "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows Forms, and you want to remove the text for all TextBox and all Label, you can do the following:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    string cType = c.GetType().ToString();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("c.Name" + c.Name + " " + cType);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cType) && cType == "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox")
    {
        c.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cType) && cType == "System.Windows.Forms.Label")
    {
        c.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```